# Querying a boolean variable versus comparing two strings in JS

Tags: javascript, string, performance, boolean

In JavaScript, is there any significant difference in performance between querying a boolean variable's value or testing for the equality of two strings.

For example, which of these, if any, is more efficient:

Boolean example:

```
var testBoolean = false;

if (testBoolean) {
   alert('false')
}
```

String example:

```
var testString = 'false';

if (testString !== 'false') {
   alert('false')
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Boolean is faster as you have one less comparison to make. You already have test set to false, but in second case you need to do string compare and push the result of that into the IF condition (which is the same as case 1 from here on)

Comment: Note that the 2 snippets aren't equivalent. The 1st will fail the `if` condition. The 2nd will pass and `alert()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jonathan, I've now edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var testString = 'false';

if (testString === false) {
   alert('I'm inside the if condition')
}
```

This will never go into the if condition because '===' and '!==' operator check both the value and the type unlike '==' and '!=' operators. But I think that is not your question.

Boolean is faster as you have one less comparison to make. You already have test set to false, but in second case you need to do string compare and push the result of that into the IF condition (which is the same as case 1 from here on)

Comment: To your 1st point about type, both values are strings. Assuming the use of `'true'` as well, the condition could pass.